# I have a file that I want to split using pipe as delimiter. How can I read the file using Perl?

Tags: perl, split, delimiter

Here is a shell script reading the file.

```
#!/bin/sh

procDate=$1
echo "Date $procDate"

file=`cat filename_$procDate.txt`

echo "$file"
```

I want to convert it to Perl and use the `split` operator with pipe `|` as delimiter.

Comment: can you post sample contents from input file and sample output you expect

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late respond. Sample is london||||america|||japan|||760|||usa|| . I want to get the 760 and throw it to a new text file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's far from clear from your question what it is that you want to do with these fields once you have split them

Your own shell script uses `cat` to copy the entire contents of your file into `$file`, but that's unlikely to be what you need to do

A very generalised Perl program would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($procDate) = @ARGV;

print "Date $procDate\n";

open my $fh, '<', "filename_$procDate.txt" or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\|/;

    # do something with @fields, for instance
    print "@fields\n";
}
```

That code splits each line on pipe `|` characters, puts the list of substrings in `@fields` and then prints it separated by spaces. But I can't guess what more you might want to do?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late respond. My text file has pipe characters in it and I want to get certain parts of it after split. For example . rachel|||||ann||||9760|||| . I want to get the 9760 and throw it into a new txt file. I appreciate your help and apologize as I am a beginner in perl. Thank you!

Comment: I tried the your code Sir. But it seems to have errors. Like Can't use global $! in "my" at ./subsdump.pl line 10, near "die $!"
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name at ./subsdump.pl line 12.
Execution of ./subsdump.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @ninjagirl: I'm sorry, there was a semicolon missing. Please try again, and note that you must pass the value of `$procDate` as a parameter on the command line

Comment: Oh my gosh! It printed the text file but without the pipe! Thank you.Now all i need is to get a specific field

Comment: @ninjagirl: That's just a list of all the elements in the `@fields` array. From your sample data in the comment above I think you want to `print $fields[10], "\n";`

Comment: i got the following error. I am so sorry I am at lost with this. Use of uninitialized value $fields[176] in concatenation (.) or string at ./subsdump.pl line 15, <$fh> line 1.

,

Comment: @ninjagirl:  Why did you choose `$fields[176]`? As far as I can tell you want the eleventh pipe-separated field, which is `$fields[10]` since they start at zero

Comment: i chose [176] cuz it is the field that i wanted to have. the comment above was just an example i have a really big file sir.

Comment: @ninjagirl: You can replace `print "@fields\n";` with `printf "%3d: %s\n", $_, $fields[$_] for 0 .. $#fields;` so that you can see what values are at what index

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open(FILE, "<filename_$procDate.txt") or die "Couldn't open file filename_$procDate.txt, $!";

while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    print "Line content is $line\n";
    my @line_content = split(/\|/, $line);
    print Dumper (\@line_content);
}

close (FILE);
```